# run py in windows error python

Tags: windows, python-3.3

I'm running by double-click a .py and from command prompt and show this error:

[image: error]

But when i'm running from IDLE it work's, what's happening this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is import from tkinter the function:

```
from tkinter import filedialog
fname = filedialog.askopenfile(filetypes=(("Excel 97-2003", "*.xls"),
                                             ("Excel", "*.xlsx")))
```

Before i have this:

```
import tkinter as tk
fname = tk.filedialog.askopenfile(filetypes=(("Excel 97-2003", "*.xls"),
                                             ("Excel", "*.xlsx")))
```